# Bug or Feature? Conversion in case stmt behave differently between versions

Tags: go, type-conversion, compiler-construction

The following code works fine with go1.11.13, however for go version above 1.12, it would cause compiler error due to conversion in the case stmt is now allowed. I wonder whether this is a bug or a new feature introduced after go1.12 but It seems that this is not mentioned in the release notes of go1.12

```
package main

type T1 struct{}
type T2 struct{}

func main() {
    var a T1
    var b T2
    _ = a
    _ = b
    a = T1(b)
    
    switch a {
    case T1(b):
    }
}
```

Comment: That's somemething you should report as a bug!

Comment: Reading through the [golang grammar](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Switch_statements), I'd say this is indeed a bug.  A case should be `"case" ExprList`, where `ExprList` is one or more comma-separated `Expression`s, `Expression` can contain a `UnaryExpression`, which in this case would be a `PrimaryExpression`, specifically a `Conversion`. A switch-case should work like `a == b` (or in this case `if a == T1(b)` which works just fine in 1.18.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will report a bug. It is just kind of weird that such a simple bug can sustain for so long without being triggered

Comment: github issue reference: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/52701